# Eigen library: Return expression instead of the vector itself

Tags: c++, eigen, compiler-optimization, eigen3

Is it possible to return some kind of expression, which then can be further used and simplified, instead of a vector itself?

I have a function `Vector3<T> f(Vector3<T> const&, Vector3<T> const&);` and I apply it in an expression of the form `g = f(a1, b1).cwiseProduct(t1) + f(a2, b2).cwiseProduct(t2)`. I wonder if this can be optimized. It seems to be unnecessary that a vector is created when `f` returns. It might be more efficient to return an "expression" instead which then can be optimized for the evaluation of `g`.

Comment: From memory you change the return type of the function to `auto` and you will be returning the expression rather than the resolved type. Couldn't find it when briefly skimming the docs.

Comment: Aren't you talking about inline functions? If both `f` and `cwiseProduct` are inlined and `Vector3<T>` is a simple struct, then the compiler should be able to optimize any object creation in between

Comment: Can we see the implementation of `f`?

Comment: @Al.G. have posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing up my comment as it might be clearer as an answer. If you return `auto` rather than `Vector3<T>` then the expression type is retained.

E.g.

```
template <typename T>
auto f(Vector3<T> const& x, Vector3<T> const& y)
{
    return x + y;
}

template <typename T>
auto use_f(Vector3<T> const& a1, Vector3<T> const& b1, Vector3<T> const& t1,
           Vector3<T> const& a2, Vector3<T> const& b2, Vector3<T> const& t2)
{
    auto f1 = f(a1, b1);
    auto f2 = f(a2, b2);
    auto g = f1.cwiseProduct(t1) + f1.cwiseProduct(t2);
    return g;
}
```

Types of `f1` & `f2`:

```
Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double,double>,Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1,0,3,1>const,Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1,0,3,1>const>
Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double,double>,Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1,0,3,1>const,Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1,0,3,1>const>
```

(this on Visual C++, might be a little different on gcc/clang)

Thanks to @Homer512, it should be noted that this approach is risky, in that if temporary objects are created in `f`, the use of `auto` will effectively return a pointer to a local variable in `f`, with the local variable going out of scope. In the [docs](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html), under "C++11 and the auto keyword", the problematic example given is

```
auto z = ((x+y).eval()).transpose();
// use or return z
```

> problem is that eval() returns a temporary object which is then referenced by the Transpose<> expression. However, this temporary is deleted right after the first line.

The docs further note that the issue can be fixed by calling `eval()` on the whole expression; however this is equivalent in our case to returning the `Vector3<T>`, which is what we were trying to avoid.

Comment: A word of warning in the answer might be prudent: Expression objects in Eigen contain sub-expressions by copy but plain objects by reference. If the expression lives longer than the referenced object, you get a dangling pointer. In the example, if `x` or `y` are temporary objects, e.g. because you call `f(a1 + c1, b1)`, this would happen. Eigen's documentation explains the pitfalls here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html

Comment: Thank you; I have amended my answer. If you have another / a better approach I'd welcome seeing an alternative answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a better approach. You already gave the correct answer. It's simply a design limitation. Eigen predates `auto` and even if it was designed with `auto` in mind, there is little one can do about it except maybe making all objects reference-counted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if you state the return type to be the `CwiseBinaryOp` instead of `auto`?  It should still work as intended...right?  Did you use ``auto`` to figure out the return type?

Comment: @Matt that wouldn't fix anything. It's not about `auto`. It's about keeping objects such as `CwiseBinaryOp` alive for more than one expression (meaning, until after destructors for temporary objects may run). To put it another way, `CwiseBinaryOp` *is* the problem. If you construct it with a plain vector, it keeps a reference to that vector. What happens when that vector is destroyed before the `CwiseBinaryOp`? Boom.

Comment: @Homer512 typing the variable as `auto` doesn't save it any more than using the actual type.  This answer basically says use `auto` instead of `Vector<...`.  My question is why not use `CwiseBinaryOp...` because `auto` turns into that anyway.  What advantage does `auto` provide here?  Replacing `auto` with `CwiseBinaryOp` worked in godbolt.  I see no problem with the answer, just curious why `auto` was chosen.  It does save alot of keystrokes.

Comment: @Matt the original question was how to return an "expression object" instead of a vector from `f(…)`. The answer is `auto`, which evaluates to `CwiseBinaryOp<…>`. Of course you could write that directly but that gets tedious very fast and may break with future Eigen revisions since it's basically an internal type. The point that the Eigen documentation makes when warning about `auto` is that these expression objects make it very simple to create dangling pointers to temporary objects, as I've explained above.